# Formula for a dynamic programming problem about stairs

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

There is a known problem, so I quote it here

> A child is running up a staircase with n steps and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps at a time. How many possible ways the child can run up the stairs?

I have two questions here:

1. How do I get an exact formula to calculate exact number for any `i` without writing a simulation?
2. How can this formula be generalized for any `k` instead of just `3`?

My math knowledge in dynamic programming is limiting me to "write a recursion, use memoization to cache results and see what simulation shows" but I'm not able to deduce a general formula to just put numbers and get out the result.

Comment: After writing a recursion you can _solve_ it. Like $a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}$ produces $\lambda^3=\lambda^2+\lambda+1$, then $a_k=\sum\limits_i c_i\lambda_i^k$ where $c_i$ depends on initial conditions.

Comment: For `k=3` i probably could take Tribonacci numbers and they should work well, but how does it work for unknown `k`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_numbers_of_higher_order

Comment: Thanks, missed this article!